# PHP to differentiate landing page for login and non login (mobile only)

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, authentication

So I have been using a theme, and its all great, and they have different php for web and mobile. but here's the thing, I want my mobile web user to land on the default homepage if they are logged in only. And if they are not logged in, I want them to land on my sign in page.

So the default home page php for mobile now is called `page-home.php` and login page is called `page-login.php`.

How to do this editing?

Comment: Check this may be it is helpfull for you [Click here](http://http://onlinewebapplication.com/php-login-page-example-with-demo/)

Comment: Hey Kyle, I've tried using the code for redirecting on the page-home. But I do not have any idea to make it specifically redirect only for non-login. when I do put the redirecting code, it created a loop, and didn't work. I saw this code "if(is_user_logged_in())" but then as what I understand, it is for the logged in user. is there any code for the non-login?

Hey Rahul, the web can't be open. "webpage not available". Tried opening other web and it all worked, but the link you gave me can't be open.